# Menu is not creating in admin/settings page?

Tags: 7, commerce, hooks

I am adding a custom module, and wants when someone install the module, menu will be added to add data in the admin/settings page...
But i am getting nothing:

Below is the code i wrote.. pricepackages is the module name i want to created

please help me ..

```
function pricepackages_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items[] = array(
        'path' => 'admin/settings/favorites/quotes',
        'title' => t('Manage Quotes'),
        //'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        //'page arguments' => array('poke_test_form'),
        'callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'callback arguments' => 'pricepackages_settings',
        //'access callback' => 'poke_access_callback',
        'access' => user_access('Access administration pages'),
    );
}
```

Settings hook is like this:

```
function pricepackages_settings()
{
    //$form['#submit'][] = 'poke_test_submit';
    $form['quote_manage'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Select User'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pricepackages_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/settings/favorites-quotes'] = array(
        'title' => t('Manage Quotes'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('pricepackages_settings'),
        //'access callback' => TRUE,
        'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    );
}
```

Comment: Dude, it's showing on left navigation, not under the admin/settings list... can you please help.. This link can also be accessable from other users i guess??

Comment: i have updated my answer check once and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module : '**Custom_menu**' with following file structure

***modules/custom***/custom_menu/

- custom_menu.info.yml
- custom_menu.module

  ```
          <?php
          /*
           * hook_toolbar()
           */
          function custom_menu_toolbar() {
              /**
               * Custom menu for Catalog
               * Array for $module should be array('Name' => 'machine_name')
               */
              $baseUrl =  \Drupal::request()->getHost().base_path();

              $modules = array(
                  'Categories' => 'categories',
                  'Products' => 'products'        
              );

              $links = array();
              $a=0;
              foreach ($modules as $module => $route) {
                  $links[$module] = array(
                      'title' => $module,
                      'type'=>'link',
                      'url' => Url::fromUri($baseUrl.'/admin/content-list/content_type/'.$route),
                      'attributes' => array(
                          'title' => $module,
                      ),
                  );
                  $a++;
              }

              //content-list/{content_type}
              $shortcut_links = [
                  '#theme'=>'links__toolbar_shortcuts',
                  '#links'=>$links,
              ];

              // Create the examples toolbar render array.
              $items['admin_menu_catalog'] = array(
                  '#type' => 'toolbar_item',
                  'tab' => array(
                      '#type' => 'link',
                      '#title' => t('Catalog'),
                      '#url' => Url::fromRoute('<front>'),
                      '#attributes' => array(
                          'title' => t('Catalog'),
                          'class' => array('toolbar-icon', 'toolbar-icon-examples'),
                      ),
                  ),

                  'tray' => array(
                      '#heading' => t('Catalog'),
                      'shortcuts' => $shortcut_links,
                  ),

                  '#weight' => 200,
                  '#attached' => array(
                      'library' => array(
                          'shortcut/drupal.shortcut',
                      ),
                  ),
              );
          }
  ```

Now you will see Catalog menu in you admin menu bar with child menus : Categories and Products.

Authentic user can see related content only. Also can add content without following the default procedure of the Drupal.